# Importing data from another sheet where the entire row is not duplicated

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a Google Sheet which has basic test data.

I need to **import every row where the entire row is completely unique.**

If any data in a row is different it should pull through to the other sheet.

Here is my test sheet with the data in 'Duplicate Rows'! and the data pulling through as is into 'Import'! https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1D1H2FLdyzr2iFwr_ENg6t2OAAsS8f71Mb4P5T_dtJ6g/edit?usp=sharing

I was going to use data validation to remove repeated rows from in the imported sheet but I can't find advice online that will consider the entire row rather than duplicate cells.

Either way **I need to prevent these repeated rows**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
=INDEX(UNIQUE(A1:C8))
```

*(**Do adjust** the formula according to your ranges and locale)*